# From Observable<T[]> to Observable<T>[]

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to fetch a bundle of data from an external API; throught an httprequest I get an `Observable<T[]>`.

While I'm waiting for the request to complete, I'm planning to create a "placeholder" that in the future would get those T, so I thought to assign to each of those placeholder an `Observable<T>`.

If I assign the T inside a

```js
request.pipe(map(array => foreach(item of array) {createPlaceholder(item)})
```

the placeholder would be created after the fetch of the data, making the "placeholder" concept pointless; so I thought about converting the `Observable<T[]>` to a `Observable<T>[]` and to assign each observable to a new array, but searching in the net I could find only the reverse (`Observable<T>[]` to `Observable<T[]>`).

Is there a way to convert a `Observable<T[]>` into an `Observable<T>[]` ?

Comment: Similarly, but as Michael2 said the code can't know beforehand how many items there are before fetching them all.

Comment: What is this for? How does the placeholder get used later? I can't imagine a use for this

Comment: Imagine a carousel; while the data gets loaded, a placeholder is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this for a generic array length.

The length of the T[] is not known at the beginning of your program and it may even change lather. So you cannot use an array for this.

Only if you know the length the array (you can model this as [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) in typescript) will have, then you can create the observables like this:

```
const serverResponse$: Observable<[T, T, T]> = ...;
const myObservables$: [Observable<T>, Observable<T>, Observable<T>] = [
  serverResponse$.pipe(map(r => r[0])),
  serverResponse$.pipe(map(r => r[1])),
  serverResponse$.pipe(map(r => r[2]))
];
```

Comment: Uh, in this specific case I always know the length of the array, since it's one of the parameters that I pass in the httprequest ("Give me N items"). So inside the myObservables$ definition I can just loop thanks to N size. I'll try this, thanks!